# exception thrown from constructor

Tags: exception, constructor, try-catch, throw, throws

I know how to throw an exception from a constructer and handle it in the main method.

but the way I know requires two steps :

1- creat a static object (holder) using the constructer with parameters that take variables.

2-creat an object using the constructer with a parameter that takes an object.

like this:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test { // open Test class.
  public static void main(String[] argus) { //open main method
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
      CHILD.holder = new CHILD("A", -1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("reEnter:");
      int b = input.nextInt();
      if (b < 0)
        System.out.println("unvalid");
      CHILD.holder.setB(b);
    }
    CHILD obj = new CHILD(CHILD.holder);
  } //end main method
} // end Test class.

class SUPER {
  private String A;
  public SUPER() {}
  public SUPER(String a) {
    A = a;
  }
  public void setA(String a) {
    A = a;
  }
  public String getA() {
    return A;
  }

}

class CHILD extends SUPER {
  public static CHILD holder = new CHILD();
  private int B;
  public CHILD() {}
  public CHILD(String a, int b) throws Exception {
    holder.setA(a);
    holder.B = 0;
    if (b < 0)
      throw new Exception("unalid , negative");
    holder.B = b;
  }
  public CHILD(CHILD obj) {
    super(obj.getA());
    B = obj.B;
  }
  public void setB(int b) {
    B = b;
  }
}
```

this way makes the code too long.

is there an alternative way to throw an exception from constructor to main?

Comment: Could you be more specific about exactly what your "problem" is? Also, please format your code so we can read it.

Comment: @Bohemian I mean is there any other way to catch an exception that has been thrown from constructor to the main?